# How to assign to queryParams multiple values with same key?

Tags: angular

I have this object:

```
  let obj = {'r' : this.queries.r}
```

this.queries.r is an array. `['ca','ba','es'].`

What i want is to assign this obj to queryParams so in url to get:

```
example.com?r=ca&r=ba&r=es.
```

Any suggestion how can i do this? I tried with httpParams but its not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set the query params manually

```
let obj = {'r' : ['ca','ba','es']}
const r = obj.r[0];
const r2 = obj.r[1];
const r3 = obj.r[2];

const url = window.location.href + '?r=' + r + '&r=' + r2 + '&r=' + r3;
window.history.pushState({}, "", url);
```

Comment: You can change this `window.location.href + '?r=' + r + '&r=' + r2 + '&r=' + r3;` to window.location.href + `?r=${r}&r=${r2}&r={r3};`